# Non-normal linear functionals on $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}_{i}\in \mathbb N$ and $X=H^*\otimes^\pi H$ is the projective tensor product. We have a natural isometry $$J:X\to X^{**}=B(H)^*$$ given by $J_{\sum k_1x_i\otimes y_i}(T)=\sum k_i\left<T(y_i),x_i\right>=\sum k_iT(x_i\otimes y_i)$ for all $T\in (H^*\otimes^\pi H)^*=B(H)$

I am looking for linear functionals which are not in $J_X$. One such example is  $\psi:B(H)\to \mathbb C$ defined as $$\psi(T)=\lim_{n, U}\left<Te_n,e_n\right>$$ where $U$ is any is non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$ , which is a well defined bounded linear functional which do not lie in the image of map $J$. Is it a complete charecterization of functional which do lie in $J_X$? If not what are the other ways we can get hold of such functionals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Not being something" is often something that is not pretty to characterize.

Here you can get an example by mixing a normal part and a non-normal part. Take one of your $\psi$, and define
$$
\varphi(T)=\psi(T)+\langle Te_1,e_1\rangle. 
$$
This is still not normal, but now it is not zero on the rank-one projection $e_1\otimes e_1$, so it cannot come from an ultrafilter.

There might be other ways to construct non-normal functionals, but I don't know about them. You are asking to fully characterize the dual of the Calkin Algebra; I don't know if that's feasible and/or known.